# Problem with vnc viewer

Tags: 11.04, vnc

I am facing a problem with vnc viewer. For example i have  a taken a system remotely using vncviewer. And if i type something in the text editor of the remote desktop few characters are not getting typed, instead it acts like a shortcut key for some actione. i.e If i press M in text editor of the remote desktop, the screen gets minimized and i am unable to type the character M. Can someone give me a solution? to get rid of this problem. Thanks in advance.

### Note:

Am using vncviewer in Natty 11.04.

Comment: It is not an exact answer to your question, but have you considered using freenx ? It offers better performance and improved security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like sticking keys problem, sometimes if in one vnc session ALT or Super key was pressed it can stick and any key pressing will be with ALT or Super keys. I had such problem when I worked via vnc with other persons. On the other hand it can be some settings on the vnc server side OS related to the sticking keys settings.